# Add property to junit xml pytest

Tags: python-3.x, xml, junit, pytest

I am trying to create a junit xml output file in pytest with custom attributes.
I searched for answers and found about xml_record_attribute and record_attribute.

```
def test(record_attribute):
    record_attribute('index', '15')
    ...
```

At first I thought it would fit to my problem but then I realized it needs to be specified in each test.

I tried to do it with pytest_runtest_call hook so it would add attributes in each test run without the need to explicitly add the attributes in each test. But then it turned out that you can't use fixtures in hook (which makes sense).

Any idea how can I add an attribute to the junit xml output file without duplicating the code?

EDIT:
I have another idea of having a decorator which does that.

```
def xml_decorator(test):
    def runner(xml_record_attribute):
        xml_record_attribute('index', '15')
        test()

    reutrn runner
```

I am trying hook it with pytest_collection_modifyitems and decorate each test but it doesn't work.

```
def pytest_collection_modifyitems(session, config, items):
    for item in items:
        item.obj = xml_decorator(item.obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a fixture that is automatically supplied to each test case:

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def record_index(record_xml_attribute):
    record_xml_attribute('index', '15')
```

Note `record_xml_attribute` is not supported for xunit2, the default junit_family for pytest v6. To use `record_xml_attribute` with pytest v6, in `pytest.ini` set

```
[pytest]
junit_family = xunit1
```

Comment: I've tried your solution, it works great when i have hard coded value like you've shown, but when i try to run over a list of attributes and record them in the method it's not working. Any Ideas?

Comment: @Bored002 are you looking to record different attributes for different tests?

Comment: Yes , that's exactly what i want , anyways i found the problem: i have to explicitly provide the junit family setting in the pytest.main invocation line , even though it's specified in the pytest.ini file . could be a bug in version 6.2.5 of pytest